# CraftCMS - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE When clicking "Settings" menu item

Tags: php, mamp, craftcms

#### Description

Hey guys, Just trying setup Craft CMS for the first time and it all seems to work fine but when I click "Settings" in the admin panel I get the error:

localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I've increased memory limit and execution time, after a lot of Googling around. But it didn't help. Sometimes I can click into the Settings page but then If I hit refresh it shows the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error again. Would love to know if anyone else had had/fixed this before? Thanks

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Install and set up fresh install from composer using MAMP on local machine.
2. Click "Settings" item in admin menu

#### Additional info

- Craft version: Craft Solo 3.4.5
- PHP version: 7.4.1
- Database driver & version: MySQL 5.7.26
- Plugins & versions: None

Comment: This issue seems specific to v5.6 of Mamp, as I had Craft CMS running fine but get this same error now that I have updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading MAMP to version 5.7